# Class on Table?

Tags: css, html, html-table

Is it not possible to style a `<table>` and its `<tr> <td>` using css classes?

For example:

```
<table class="calendar_table">
<tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Datum</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Event</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Type</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then using something like this CSS:

```
.calendar_table {
    width:880px;
}
.calendar_table tr {
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Comment: you wrote a code already, why asking, test it. :D

Comment: I'm trying to remember if putting margin and padding on a tr is actually meaningful. If you apply those styles to the TDs then it should work.

Comment: @Chris Margins don't apply to both TR and TD elements. Padding doesn't apply to TR elements, but does apply to TD elements.

Comment: HTML has classes, CSS doesn't. Things that people mistakenly call "CSS classes" include properties, rule sets, class selectors, and (all) selectors. Please avoid the term "CSS classes", while people can often figure out what you mean from context, it is better to just use the right term in the first place.

Comment: Oh, and you probably should replace `<td><h2>` with `<th scope="col">`

Comment: @David The correct term is "CSS class selector".

Comment: @Šime Vidas — that was the third of the four common things people call "A CSS class" that I listed.

Comment: @David Yes, I only wanted to make it clear (for the record) what the correct term is (since you didn't explicitly state it).

Comment: Hmm, I thought jamietelin meant rule set. Goes to show why "CSS classes" is such a rubbish term!

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Thanks. I thought that was the case but wasn't in a position to actually find references to back me up. I figured somebody would follow it up though. Cheers. :) Hopefully I'll remember for next time too. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible, it should work properly!

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8RxgQ/)

Have fun, you can do whatever you want! I don't recommend using `<table>`though, unless it is used to present structured data that is meant to be in a table. If it is to draw a layout, use `<div>` and CSS!

Comment: Thanks, It did work. I had some weird kind of cache and therefor it didnt show correctly.

Comment: You can disable cache in your browser settings for testing purpose or hit CTRL + R and major browser to do  a refresh clearing cache.

Answer (score 4):

As Aleks wrote, I would define css for the table itself too. But **no nested brackets** in css definition like: table.custom_class  { ...  **td, th { ... }** }.

```
<table class="custom_class">
  <tr>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Giovanni</td>
    <td>Rovelli</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Roland</td>
    <td>Mendel</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The following CSS example can be used:

```
table.custom_class {
    border:solid 5px #006CFF;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    line-height:22px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0018ff; 
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
table.custom_class th {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color:#98dcff;
  border:solid 2px #006CFF;
}
table.custom_class td {
  padding: 20px;
  border:solid 1px #006CFF;
}
table.custom_class tr {
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
}
```

You can see it in action https://jsfiddle.net/16L9h2ft/

Answer (score 3):

The answers above are either old, or not answered properly, as they are ignoring the styling of the `table` itself and not just `td` or `th` etc. elements.

If we would have a table like this:

```
<table class="custom_class">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header 1</th>
      <th>header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row value 1</td>
      <td>row value 2</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then in `.css` we should put:

```
table.custom_class  {
  border: 1px solid black;

  td, th {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  What you have [is working to some extent](http://jsfiddle.net/bkJkV/1/) (with tweaks).

To style the td, use:

```
.calendar_table td {
}
```

Or:

```
.calendar_table tr td {
}
```

will also work.

For setting attributes such as borders, colors, and sizes this is the cleaner way to do it, over embedding that information in HTML.

This approach is great with data tables where the information naturally should be presented in a table.  If you are laying out data use more semantically correct tags such as `<div>` and `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

Table rows don't take padding, TDs do.

Change your style to:

```
.calendar_table td {
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Comment: The `margin` property doesn't apply to TD elements.

Answer (score 1):

- Tables expand if necessary to let content fit
- As far as I know, table rows do not have margin or padding

These layout rules apply no matter how you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Nice looking green table theme :

https://jsfiddle.net/sujayun/qwsLk3aL/

```
table.namTblCls
{
    color:purple;
    border: #004400 4px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size:16px;
}

table.namTblCls th
{
    text-align: center;
    color:yellow;
    background-color:#008800;
    border: #004400 2px solid;
    padding: 20px;
}

table.namTblCls td
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border: #004400 1px solid ;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
}

table.namTblCls tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #DDFFDD;
}

table.namTblCls tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #BBFFBB;
}
```